# Double and Add using NAF

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am new in Elliptic curve, so I started with implementing (single scalar multiplication) I have done it the simple way, and then I moved to Double & Add algorithm later with NAF form.

When I moved to the NAF form. Two versions of algorithm gave me two different results. And I'm not sure what did I miss.

I'm using ECC defined as: $y^2=x^3 - 2x +2$ over the finite field $GF(23)$

I'm trying to compute $7P$ where $P=[5,5]$, with simple double and add the result is $7P=[5,18]$ but with NAF $7P=[5,-5]$

I believe the reason is I compute $7P$ in double & add with NAF as $7P = 8P - P = O - [5,5] = [5,-5]$ so I'm not sure if I miss some important condition when working in NAF form.

Computed points:

```
1P:     [5, 5]
2P:     [15, 14]
3P:     [16, 15]
4P:     [11, 0]
5P:     [16, 8]
6P:     [15, 9]
7P:     [5, 18]
8P:     O
9P:     [5, 5]
10P:    [15, 14]
11P:    [16, 15]
12P:    [11, 0]
13P:    [16, 8]
14P:    [15, 9]
15P:    [5, 18]
16P:    O
```

double & add
$7P = 1P + 2P + 4P = [5,18]$

double & add with NAF
$7P = 8P - P = O - [5,5] = [5,-5]$

Comment: Hint: in $\operatorname{GF}(23)$, what's another common notation for $-5$?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I totally missed this. I feel bad for missing this one.

Answer (score 1):

It work's as expected, just forgot that the coordinate negation over a finite field GF(p) must use modular arithmetic. So -5 mod23 is 18.